# I am working on dates on django, Is there a way to compare the rendered date on html to check if it is less than 3 days left on current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have this code where it normally displays all of the number of rows on database. Is there a way to compare the returned date(Promised Date) to javascript or jquery so i can highlight all of the dates that are less than 3 days from the today's date. Thanks

```
<div class="container">
  <table id="requirement_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Applicant Name</th>
        <th>Requirement</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
        <th>Promised Date</th>
        <th>Completed</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for req in app_requirements %}
      <tr>
        <th>{{ req.applicant }}</th>
        <th>{{ req.requirement }}</th>
        <th>{{ req.remarks }}</th>
        <th>{{ req.date_promised }}</th>
        <th>{{ req.completed }}</th>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but can't help you much without seeing how the date is returned. Convert it to javascript date object and compare it with whatever date you need.

Comment: @cray. the date is returned like this

Dec. 16, 2019

tried to compared it to string and it matched. How can i convert it to javascript or jquery date object?

Comment: [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) for converting string to date. However yours is not in ISO format. If you can't change that use a library as the link states or convert it to ISO format using javascript. I see that you can split string on `.` and `,` to get 3 pieces and then you should change the month name to numeric value.

Comment: Seems that JS can actually accept your format aswell. Try `Date.parse(yourDateHere);` and see if it works for you.

Comment: Wow thanks. the Date.parse works for me. Can you post your answer so i can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert String to Date object and compare it with the date you need.

```
let myDate = getDateSomewhere();
Date.parse(myDate);
```